# How to use Jess in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, jess

I'm creating a school project and my instructor demand to use Jess expert system shell. How can I use jess in Android Studio?

Comment: Does your instructor also demand to use android studio? Do you have Jess 8.0 available?

Comment: no. I choose to use android studio as my IDE. I have'nt downloaded any Jess. I am still learning jess. and the only available is a trial version of jess

Comment: Well, then just use Eclipse. - You shouldn't have a license problem with Jess 7.x being a school anyway and you can use the trial version - your teacher ought to know.

Comment: Sadly I'm at the middle of my work using android studio. And I dont have Eclipse.